# Making a scroll bar in game

Tags: c++

I'm making a scroll bar for chat box in my game now but I can't calculate the height of thumb in scroll bar.

I try

`(containerHeight / contentHeight) * thumbHeight`

but it's not working.

please give me an idea, thanks.

Illustration:
[image: illustration of variables]

Comment: Hi man, `containerHeight`, `contentHeight`, and `thumbHeight` are all variables internal to your program.  We have no idea what they are supposed to do or what data it represents.

Comment: that ratio seems reasonable. Are you sure you're not getting the division truncated because of integer variables?

Comment: if it helps to make the question more clear, I added an illustration of what I *assume* the variables mean

Comment: How is it not working?  How is this not just a "debug my code" question?

Comment: sorry for unclear question.
by the way, thanks for the illustration. I add text from bottom of the chat box and when the new message comes I move the first text up as well as the others but when I add many texts my scroll bar can't scroll to see all of the texts.

Comment: @aratn0n "the scroll bar can't scroll" is still not much of a description to help us find the answer. We don't know how your code is structured and we don't know how you choose to position or size the scroll bar or any of your elements. We don't know if it's a silly oversight like integer truncation or if your logic is wrong. In fact, I don't even know if my diagram is correct, since you haven't told us how your variables are being used.

Comment: When you need a GUI which is advanced enough to have scrollbars, you should look into using a GUI library.

Comment: If you can edit the question to make it clearer, defining each variable and maybe adding a picture, it will be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for the equation: `X / Y = A / B`, where `X` is to `A` what `Y` is to `B` then algebra yields:

```
X / Y = A / B
```

Multiply both sides by `Y` to get:

```
X = (A / B) * Y
```

Using some variables I made up because I don't completely know if Jimmy's interpretation is alright:

```
TabHeight / ScrollBarHeight = ViewableHeight / TotalHeight
TabHeight = (ViewableHeight / TotalHeight) * ScrollBarHeight
```

As long as you know any 3 variables in the equation, you can solve for the 4th.